# Misfiring event for Dynamic control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dynamic

In my Asp.net Application, I created a ImageButton "Login" dynamically. Also added a attribute as "OnClick" to the "Login", during Page_load. Again am adding same attribute as "OnClick" to the "Login".

Code Behind:

```
public partial class Calendar : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      ImageButton Login = new ImageButton();
      Login.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "InClick();");
      Page.Controls.Add(0,Login);
   }

   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Login.Attributes.Remove("OnClick");
      Login.Attributes.Add("OnClick","OutClick();");
   }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function InClick()
  {
     alert("From InClick()");
  }
  function OutClick()
  {
     alert("From OutClick()");
  }
</script>
```

While the Page_Loads the OnClick event should be as **"InClick()"**. Then If, the Button_Clicked then the OnClick event should be as **"OutClick()"**.

For me  the first Attribute is firing rightly, once I clicked the **Login** button. But the second Attribute is firing only after double clicking the **"Login"** button.

Comment: In the `Button_Click` function, try removing the "OnClick" attribute before adding the new one

Comment: Ya...Just did it. But It doesn't work.

Comment: Well then show your actual code, not just made up snippets

Comment: @Ian take a look at my code...